# Deserializing Json data in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, deserialization, javascriptserializer

i have some json data, and i want to convert it into plain text, below is the content i am getting in JSON

```
{"items":[{"id":1371503932001,"name":"shure_ksm_mics","adKeys":null,"shortDescription":"shure_ksm_mics","longDescription":null,"creationDate":"1325934831982","publishedDate":"1325934831982","lastModifiedDate":"1325937858839","linkURL":null,"linkText":null,"tags":[],"videoStillURL":null,"thumbnailURL":null,"referenceId":null,"length":204130,"economics":"AD_SUPPORTED","playsTotal":null,"playsTrailingWeek":null,"FLVURL":"rtmp:\/\/brightcove.fcod.llnwd.net\/a500\/d19\/&media\/13421268001\/13421268001_1371835938001_shure-ksm-mics&1325955600000&1818a465ec2632081e214f18376d6a4d","renditions":[],"FLVFullLength":{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"shure_ksm_mics.flv","encodingRate":1000000,"frameHeight":480,"frameWidth":640,"id":1371835938001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":29068243,"uploadTimestampMillis":1325934831973,"url":"rtmp:\/\/brightcove.fcod.llnwd.net\/a500\/d19\/&media\/13421268001\/13421268001_1371835938001_shure-ksm-mics&1325955600000&1818a465ec2632081e214f18376d6a4d","videoCodec":"ON2","videoContainer":"FLV","videoDuration":204130},"videoFullLength":{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"shure_ksm_mics.flv","encodingRate":1000000,"frameHeight":480,"frameWidth":640,"id":1371835938001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":29068243,"uploadTimestampMillis":1325934831973,"url":"rtmp:\/\/brightcove.fcod.llnwd.net\/a500\/d19\/&media\/13421268001\/13421268001_1371835938001_shure-ksm-mics&1325955600000&1818a465ec2632081e214f18376d6a4d","videoCodec":"ON2","videoContainer":"FLV","videoDuration":204130}}],"page_number":0,"page_size":100,"total_count":-1}
```

i have created below class

```
public class VideoList
{
    public VideoList() { }
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set 
        {
            value = _name;
        }
    }
}
```

currently i just want to get name.
how can do this using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavacriptSerializer class.

Comment: Check this link out to see if it helps out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982616/deserializing-json-to-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed model structure, but this should work:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.Deserialize<VideoList>(json);

public class VideoList
{
    public List<Video> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Video
{
    public string Name { get; set;}

    // you can extend this class with additional propertie
    // to get the rest of json data
}
```