# Receive and parse JSON objects in controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am sending an array of json objects with jQuery to a controller in asp.net mvc3. The problem is when I receive the stringified version of the objects on the server because it looks null.

When I receive the json I want it to be converted to a list of models.

The json I send is:

```
[{"0": [{"name": "name1", "value": "value1"}, {"name": "name2", "value": "value2"}]}, {"1": [{"name": "name3", "value": "value3"}, {"name": "name4", "value": "value4"}]}]  



public class Example
{
   public List<Model> Values {get; set;}
}

public ActionResult functionName(Example example) { //... }
```

What I want is to have that json string converted to a list of two `Model` objects.

Comment: did you set the content type of the request to application/json?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DeSerializing JSON to C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982616/deserializing-json-to-c-sharp)

Comment: @GoranObradovic yes. It reaches the controller but the content of `example` is null.

Comment: How does your Model class look like?

Comment: @3nigma is `JsonConvert` a solution?

Comment: @GoranObradovic with 3 `string` properties and 2 `DateTime`

Comment: Well, then this json you are sending does not really look like your model?

Comment: Please post your jQuery code!

Comment: @GoranObradovic it doesn't look the same because the inputs are generated using `BeginCollectionItem`

Comment: Ah, I was using knockoutjs for that and had no problems, but I had json as model, serialized from server-side class. Try manually creating your json model from console and posting it to check if it works when it is same as model class.